# asp.net mvc: How to pass nullable boolean in Ajax data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

I have a grid, which I update via ajax so it filters automatically when typing. My controller therefor returns a partialviewresult. (similar to http://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net/Grid/GlobalSearch ).

Now I want to pass some extra parameters and I try to pass nullable booleans to my Controller, and this seems to be my problem.

When testing I often have

> "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '?'"

or some issues around 'True', etc...

```
//...
 var p = this.value;
      delay(function () {
    $('.mvc-grid').mvcgrid({
          query: 'filterBasic=' + p,
          data: { 'foo': @ViewBag.ParamFoo, 'bar': @ViewBag.ParamBar},
          reload: true
        });
//..
```

This is the controller signature:

```
public PartialViewResult FooGrid(string filterBasic, bool? foo = null, bool? foo = null)
```

When changing this to strings it works as I can pass "", "true" or "false":

```
public PartialViewResult FooGrid(string filterBasic, string foo = null, string foo = null)
```

and inside this method I manually convert values:

```
 bool? ssfoo = null;
      bool? ssbar = null;
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(foo))
      {
        try
        {
          ssfoo = Convert.ToBoolean(foo);
        }
        catch { }
      }
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bar))
      {
        try
        {
          ssbar = Convert.ToBoolean(bar);
        }
        catch { }
      }
```

I've tried to use a converter, but can't find how to do it for a nullable bool.

$.ajaxSetup({
  converters : {
    'bool' : function (v) { return v == 'true' || v == 'True'; }
  }
});

For now I've changed everything to pass strings and manually convert strings to booleans... but this doesn't seem to be the nicest thing.

Comment: Use `var foo = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.ParamFoo))` etc and  then `data: { foo: foo, bar: bar },`

Comment: And do not change the parameter types - you passing a representation of a `bool` so the parameter should be `bool?` (and everything is sent to the server as text - there is no concept of a `string` or a `bool` in the request)

Comment: thanks, i'll give it a try.